No valid addresses for Libp2p node
I´m trying to create a node with lib but when I add the addresses filed, the next error comes out:
P2PService.js:83 Error al crear el nodo: CodeError: no valid addresses were provided for transports [@libp2p/websockets]
    at DefaultTransportManager.listen (transport-manager.ts:260:1)
    at DefaultTransportManager.afterStart (transport-manager.ts:75:1)
    at components.ts:75:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy._invokeStartableMethod (components.ts:71:1)
    at Proxy.afterStart (components.ts:90:1)
    at Libp2pNode.start (libp2p.ts:217:1)
    at async createLibp2p (index.ts:170:1)
    at async createNode (P2PService.js:60:1)

I made sure the port was available and even tried different ones but it's impossible to get my node to work. I'm trying to create a chat app that connects individual nodes to a hub and then provide their emails to find each other.
The code is this:
import { createLibp2p } from 'libp2p'
import { createFromJSON } from '@libp2p/peer-id-factory'
import { webSockets } from '@libp2p/websockets'
import { noise } from '@chainsafe/libp2p-noise'
import { yamux } from '@chainsafe/libp2p-yamux'
import { kadDHT } from '@libp2p/kad-dht'
import PeerId from 'peer-id'
import { generateKeyPairFromSeed } from '@libp2p/crypto/keys'

const chatProtocol = '/mychat/1.0.0'

export async function createPeerId(privKey) {
  try {
    
    const peerIdPrivateKey = await generateKeyPairFromSeed("Ed25519", privKey)
    console.log('peerIdPrivateKey:', peerIdPrivateKey)

    const peerId = await PeerId.createFromPrivKey(peerIdPrivateKey.bytes)
    console.log('peerId:', peerId)

    localStorage.setItem('peerId', JSON.stringify(peerId))
    console.log('Archivo JSON escrito con éxito')

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al crear el PeerId:', error)
  }
}

function getStoredPeerId() {
  const peerDataJSON = localStorage.getItem('peerId')
  if (!peerDataJSON) {
    console.error('No se encontraron datos de PeerId en localStorage')
    return null
  }
  return JSON.parse(peerDataJSON)
}

export async function createNode(privKey) {

  await createPeerId(privKey)

  const storedPeerId = getStoredPeerId()
  console.log('PeerId almacenado recuperado:', storedPeerId)

  const peerId = await createFromJSON(storedPeerId)
  console.log('PeerId creado desde el JSON:', peerId)

  if (!peerId) {
    console.log('No se encontraron datos de PeerId')
    return
  }

  try {
    const node = await createLibp2p({
      peerId: peerId,
      addresses: {
        listen: ['/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/10333']
      },
      transports: [webSockets()],
      connectionEncryption: [noise()],
      streamMuxers: [yamux()],
      services: {
        dht: kadDHT({
        })
      }      
    })
    
    await node.start()
    console.log('libp2p has started', node)

    const listenAddrs = node.getMultiaddrs()
    console.log('libp2p is listening on the following addresses: ', listenAddrs)

    return node
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al crear el nodo:', error)
  }
}

